# How to fill DataGridViewComboBoxColumn items differently for each row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the following code:

```
        private void FillJobDescriptionItems(int rowIndex)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewTimesheetEntries.Rows[rowIndex];

            // Get the job number and title, and customer name for a specific job
            Job? jobDescriptionObj = (Job?)row.Cells[jobDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index].Value;
            if (jobDescriptionObj != null)
            {
                VwJob? jobVwJob = (VwJob?)_dbContext.VwJobs.Where(x => x.Id == jobDescriptionObj.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (jobVwJob != null)
                {
                    List<VwJob> jobCustomers = (List<VwJob>)(_dbContext.VwJobs.Where(x => x.CustomerId == jobVwJob.CustomerId).ToList());
                    DataGridViewComboBoxCell jobDescriptionCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[JobDescription.Index];
                    jobDescriptionCell.Items.Clear();
                    jobDescriptionCell.ValueMember = "Id";
                    jobDescriptionCell.DisplayMember = "Name";
                    foreach (VwJob jobcust in jobCustomers)
                    {
                        CustomerJobStatus custJobStatusObj = new CustomerJobStatus();
                        custJobStatusObj.Id = jobcust.Id;
                        custJobStatusObj.Name = jobcust.JobNumber + " | " + jobcust.CustomerName + " | " + jobcust.Title;

                        jobDescriptionCell.Items.Add(custJobStatusObj);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Cells[JobDescription.Index].Value = jobDescriptionObj.JobNumber + " |  | " + jobDescriptionObj.Title;
                }
            }
        }
```

Which is being called in the `DataBindingComplete` event. The `DataGridView` is coming back empty for this column.

Please can someone tell me how to fill each `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` with the items for just one customer?

Thanks.

I've tried using `Items.Add` and also `DataSource` as well, but with no luck.